# constraintWithItem crashes on simulator for iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I bounced into an opposite situation as the usual. On running my app in the simulator it crashes on the apparently harmless instruction:

```
topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:appendino attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.backStatus attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
```

while it works seamlessly on my 3.5'' iPhone. I have no 4'' iPhone to test it on, but the simulator also crashes when simulating the former format.
It does not report any message neither in the console nor in the device logs, but for a crash address, and it happens at the creation of the constraint rather than at its application.

libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x1cc388a:  pushl  %ebp
0x1cc388b:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1cc388d:  pushl  %ebx
0x1cc388e:  pushl  %edi
0x1cc388f:  pushl  %esi
0x1cc3890:  subl   $2028, %esp
0x1cc3896:  calll  0x1cc389b                 ; objc_exception_throw + 17
0x1cc389b:  popl   %ebx
0x1cc389c:  movl   $16, (%esp)
0x1cc38a3:  calll  0x1cd6678                 ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
0x1cc38a8:  movl   %eax, %esi
0x1cc38aa:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x1cc38ad:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1cc38b0:  calll  *1722297(%ebx)
0x1cc38b6:  movl   %eax, %edi
0x1cc38b8:  movl   1721937(%ebx), %eax
0x1cc38be:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1cc38c2:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0x1cc38c5:  calll  0x1cd30a4                 ; objc_msgSend

Might it be a bug of iOS 7? Or what?

No problem in the iPad simulator nor on the device.

Answer (score -1):

Trust device, not simulator. Simulator is just that - simulator.

Comment: Of course. But the crash appears at start-up and so I cannot use the simulator any longer, especially for the iPhone 5 tests and provision of screen shots, given I own no iPhone 5. Moreover it could hint to some hidden problem I would like to eschew.

Comment: The issue boils down to an UIImageView used in the constraint that is not assigned and remains nil for unknown reasons just on the simulator and moreover just in Italian, notwithstanding I have a single storyboard.